# caffe:AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LabelMap'

Tags: python-2.7, caffe, ubuntu-16.04

The caffe is installed on the Ubuntu server,and it test is ok. I just run the following code on the Ubutun(16.04) cloud server:

```
  import caffe
   from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2


   label_map = caffe_pb2.LabelMap()
```

and I have run the command as following which provided by the internet, but there is still error:

command:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$/home2/challenge98/caffe/python:$PYTHONPATH
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LabelMap'
```

Could you guys give me some advices how to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should install the version of new caffe([https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe](https://github.com/weiliu89)) for you work, although you have installed the BVLC caffe. –