# AttributeERROR:'module' object has no attribute 'labelmap'

Tags: caffe, solid-state-drive

I am using ubuntu 14.04.I gited the ssd branch caffe and met the problem below when I bash caffe-ssd/data/VOC0712/create_data.sh.(I named the ssd branch caffe caffe-ssd)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/lab/caffe-ssd/data/VOC0712/../../scripts/create_annoset.py", line 107, in 
label_map = caffe_pb2.LabelMap()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LabelMap'
```

this is my PYTHONPATH:

```
lab@lab:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/lab/caffe-ssd/python
```

I have also added below words in the file create_annoset.py. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
 sys.path.append("/home/lab/caffe-ssd/python")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [caffe:AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LabelMap'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409093/caffeattributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-labelmap)

Comment: thanks for your remindness. I have met the same problem just as LuFFy. But it is a little different. I will post my problem under that question

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe problem is that the ssd-branch I've git is original version ssd. I d So I download the ssd-branch zip from github

https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd

and unzip it.Then I met a new problem when I bash create_data.sh like below:

no module named _caffe

though that I could import caffe in the python shell. I have referred that this problem came up due to the $PYTHONPATH confusion,Then I add the below words in the document caffe_root/scripts/create_annosets.py:

sys.path.insert(0,"YOUR_SSD_BRANCH_CAFFE/python")

all done.